# GMSMapStyle unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to change my google map style in ios. For that I am trying to implement this code. 
[GMSMapStyle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/styling)

I am importing `import GoogleMaps`. But I am getting this error `Use of unresolved identifier GMSMapStyle`. Can anybody help me to which module I have to import to avoid this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that I was trying to implement this code in GoogleMapSDK version 2.0.1. But it is available from 2.1.0.

Comment: Where did you download the newer version of library from? I'm looking for manual download URL.

Answer (score 7):

While updating an app, I was getting a similar error but with mapType:

'Use of unresolved identifier 'kGMSTypeTerrain' with the following code:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView!
  googleMapView.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain
```

Took me a couple of days to resolve this item. I thought I had an issue with my GoogleMaps IOS api so did a cocoa pod install (when I should of done a pod update) but it did not fix the issue.  I finally came across the issue noted above with mapStyle.  As it turns out, with Swift 3,

```
googleMapView.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain
```

should be changed to

```
googleMapView.mapType = .terrain
```

Likewise for the other map types.

Answer (score 2):

Use this that:

example:

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = GMSMapViewType.terrain
```

Answer (score 0):

In older version also you can add map style by the following method

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
    // Available map types: kGMSTypeNormal, kGMSTypeSatellite,kGMSTypeHybrid,
    // kGMSTypeTerrain, kGMSTypeNone
    // Set the mapType to Satellite
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
    view = mapView
```