# Google Maps SDK iOS Satellite View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

How do I get the Satellite View on my iOS App? The code on the Google SDK Website doesn't work. I'm running the latest version of Xcode.

If I use the provided code on the Google SDK Website, I get this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'kGMSTypeSatellite'.

The code I'm using from the Google Developer website is:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.8683, longitude: 151.2086, zoom: 6)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
```

Thanks.

Comment: what does _The code on the Google SDK Website doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: @hongsy it says: Use of unresolved identifier 'kGMSTypeSatellite'

Comment: please [edit] your post and provide working code and error messages.

Comment: @hongsy There you go, I've changed it.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/a/59817421/6619250 help?

Comment: you should call "mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite" like this "let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = GMSMapViewType. satellite".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling like this:
 `mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite`

You should call your mapView like

`let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = GMSMapViewType.satellite`.

Comment: Hi There, The Code doesn't give me any errors, but my Map is completely Blank. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: please make sure you have added all permissions in info.plist

Comment: Hi There, Yes the Map does work in the Standard mapView. I copied everything from the Google Maps SDK Website into my Info.plist, Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where you are calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

Came across the issue noted above with GMSMapView.  With Swift 3,

```
mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
```

should be changed to

```
mapView.mapType = .satellite
```

and likewise for the other map types. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228955) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the address label in Satelite View use-

```
        self.mapView.mapType = .hybrid
```