# How would i display Google Maps SDK iOS Satellite view using googles own example

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have loaded the Google Maps SDK for iOS and as per the given example in the google docs shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#add-map). Building my app with this example works fine which is awesome. However, I'd like to show a satellite view instead of the standard view.

I've found you can change the map types as per the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#change_the_map_type). However, I'm not sure how to do so with the given example.

### Google's MapView Example.

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.frame, camera: camera)
self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

### Google's MapType Example.

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = .satellite
```

### My Current Solution (Working)

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.frame, camera: camera)
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

> **My Question**
>
> How would I combine both `view.addSubview(mapView)` & `mapView.mapType = .satellite`

I did find this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817165/google-maps-sdk-ios-satellite-view), but couldn't really make heads or tails of it. Probably due to my lack of experience.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the line `mapView.mapType = .satellite` before the line `view.addSubview(mapView)`?

Comment: And that is why I'm a novice. +1 (That did it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera) 
mapView.mapType = .satellite 
view.addSubview(mapView)
```